# How to structure a prometheus exporter with multiple set of metrics and targets

Tags: go, prometheus, exporter

I'm developing a golang prometheus custom exporter with multiple set of metrics. So far I have one collector like this:

```
func systemCollector()*sMetrics{

     return &sMetrics{
        metrics1: prometheus.NewDesc ...
        metric2: ...
}
```

With the mandatory **collect** and **describe** functions. However should I do this for all my collectors or should I only have one collect and one describe with collector functions feeding them metrics?